"Fourier Transformation" of angle spinors to twistor variables
This relates to the derivation of equation (5.15) if Elvang and Huang's textbook. The idea is to transform the spinor helicity variables we are using, $(|i\rangle_{\dot{a}},[j|^a)$ to go into twistor space. The Fourier transformation is given as
\begin{equation}
|i\rangle^{\dot{a}}\rightarrow -i\frac{\partial}{\partial\langle\tilde{\mu}_i|_{\dot{a}}}
\end{equation}
I am already struggling from the start with setting up the integral. The only thing I have written down is that the Fourier transformation (modulo a factor of $2\pi$) is that I think it should be
\begin{equation}
\int\prod^n_{i=1}d^2|i\rangle e^{i\langle i|_{\dot{a}}|\tilde{\mu}_i\rangle^{\dot{a}}}
\end{equation}
where the product is over $i=1,2,...,n$ particles. I think it is partially the notation confusing me since, for example, if I had an ordinary function that I wanted to Fourier transform in $d=3$, $|\mathbf{q}|^{-2}$ then I would just throw it into $\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}|\mathbf{q}|^{-2}$ and plug-in $d^3\mathbf{q} = q^2d\cos(\theta)d\phi$ with proper integration bounds of course and defining $\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r} = qr\cos(\theta)$. But in this case, I am lost. (The discussion on this is pages 99-100 in the textbook referenced prior (or lecture notes).)
My guess would be to multiply by a suitable test function as one method. However another method would be to insert a complete basis of states (which is weird to say since these are spinors), or even hit the state with the translation operator$P^{\dot{a}b} = -\sum_i|i\rangle^{\dot{a}}[i|^b$, then insert a complete basis of states in order to perform the proper integration (but I do not know what the "basis of states" would be in this case).
Or, if I am dead wrong in anything stated, I of course ask for any help or guidance (thank you).

In order to set up the correct Fourier transform, we can start from the usual one:
$$
f(x) = \int d^4p ~e^{ip\cdot x} f(p)
$$
The first thing we need to do is write things in terms of spinors using $$p_{a\dot{a}} = |i\rangle_a|i]_{\dot{a}}.$$
This gives
$$
\int d^4p ~e^{ip\cdot x} f(p) = \int d^2|i\rangle_a d^2|i]_{\dot{a}}~|J| e^{i[i|x|i\rangle} f(|i],|i\rangle),
$$
where $|J|$ is some Jacobian.
However, we note that this needs to be evaluated on the incidence relation:
$$
\langle\tilde{\mu}_i|_{a} + [i|^{\dot{a}}x_{a\dot{a}} = 0.
$$
So the fourier transform we actually need is
$$
f(x) = \int  d^2|i\rangle_a~|J| d^2|i]_{\dot{a}} e^{i[i|x|i\rangle} \delta^2(\langle\tilde{\mu}_i|_{a} + [i|^{\dot{a}}x_{a\dot{a}})~ f(|i],|i\rangle)
$$
Eliminating the square bracket using the delta function and performing two of the integrals then gives
$$
f(x) = \int  d^2|i\rangle_a~|J| e^{-i\langle i \tilde{\mu}_i\rangle} f(\langle{\tilde{\mu}}|,|i\rangle)
$$
